# 6GB of "other" on my iPhone 3GS, should I do a clean install of ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

Since I installed iOS 6 there have been many issues with my iPhone 3GS. I now have 6GB of "unknown" stuff in the iTunes breakdown, and the phone became much slower, could there be a connection between the two?

Is it possible to do a clean install of iOS6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all settings and information from your iPhone using "Erase All Content and Settings" in Settings > General > Reset.

If that doesn't help you can also try the same from iTunes, see [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414) for details.

1. Connect your iPhone to your computer
2. Select it when it appears under Devices
3. Select the Summary tab, and click the Restore button
4. verify to reset to factory settings and erase all data

Afterwards you can restore your data again from a previous backup in iTunes.